# getting "Error: Invalid Geojson Object" even though my json is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, leaflet

I've been trying to create a proportional symbols map using Leaflet and jQuery. Currently getting the error "invalid Geojson object." I have validated my json using jsonlint.com and it is valid. I think the error must be from my method of getting the json.

I ran into a CORS error trying to use my json as a local file, so I have hosted it online, here is the URL: https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g

I have tried to put it in my Javascript as follows:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g")
```

I tried using `$.get` instead of `$.getJSON` but that didn't work either.

Not sure how to proceed. Can someone help?

Comment: what is the error are you getting?

Comment: I think you have may have some other error that isn't covered by your question. Using `$.getJSON(url, success_function)` works for me

Comment: the error says "Error: Invalid GeoJSON object." nothing else.

Comment: You haven't posted the code that gets the error. But you might consider using the leaflet-ajax plugin which handles all the complicated stuff for you - https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax

Comment: my code is https://jsfiddle.net/sophhGIS/8nadyhux/16/ but it doesnt work at the moment, but i don't know how to try fixing it until i have got rid of this geojson error :-(

Comment: Where does `CTHValueSymbols` get called? And you seem to be loading the Json file with `$.getJSON` but not doing anything with the data.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to validate yours geoJson through different sites and http://geojsonlint.com/ doesn't work until I'd removed

> "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},

If it doesn't help - look at yours Leaflet code, you should put your data inside [L.geoJSON() method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#geojson)

Comment: I have removed this bit and although it works in Geojsonlint.com when I input my code in notepad++ I still get the "Error: invalid geojson object" error in my web console when I load my page in firefox. not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working, were you possibly not handeling the result properly?

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g", function(data){
  $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'></div>
```

EDIT: Also, when testing here: http://geojsonlint.com/  it says that your geoJSON is not valid with a little better error message `Line 1: old-style crs member is not recommended, this object is equivalent to the default and should be removed`

EDIT2: It appears that removing `"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}` from your json makes it valid and plots properly.

Comment: I'm not sure. my full code is a lot longer but the only error in the console is "Error: Invalid GeoJSON object."
i have copied my code to here: https://jsfiddle.net/sophhGIS/8nadyhux/16/ but it doesn't work. i don't know how to get it to work, but i can't even try in notepad++ until i've got rid of this geojson error. is there something i'm missing?

Comment: That is probably coming from from where you are trying to consume the data. Can you post that code as well?

Comment: just edited my comment to include a jsfiddle link with my code :-)

Comment: @sophhGIS I edited my answer, check that out see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Literally just remove `,"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}` from the file and it should work. Dont forget the preceeding comma!

Comment: it works in geojsonlint but in notepad++ i am still seeing the error "invalid GeoJSON object" :S

Comment: I can't reproduce it there, sorry.